# Reverse chronological order - how important is consistency?

Tags: resume

My resume is currently sorted in reverse chronological order. However, this means that in my education section, a one week leadership course is listed above my degree. These are the only two entries in this section. Is it okay to list the course below the degree and leave everything else in chronological order?

Comment: Does the one week leadership course even merit mention on your resume?  To me it would take up lines better devoted to relevant information that I would have to remove to keep my resume at 2 pages.  Even if I Didnt have 25 years to condense I am not sure I see value in a week long leadership course on your resume... Try and think like an employer.

Comment: Does including the date on education degrees indicate age to a certain extent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I include things like leadership training in a seperate professional development section, as opposed to grouping it with education;  the exception would be if the leadership course was, for example, a module as part of an ongoing MBA.

I do this even if the professional development course was conducted at a University (which, in my case, it was).

As an employer, (who screens resumes and interviews staff) I wouldn't expect to find a leadership course grouped with University and High School results, but rather alongside other professional skills and courses.

If the course was a post-graduate module while you were still at university, then chronological order is fine.

Comment: Agreed, I certainly don't mix training courses with my university degree on my resume.

Comment: In the current climate for most positions I'm cutting 90% of the applicants before the interview.  I tend to review someone's work profile first, then their professional development, and their education last.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the job you are going for, if you are going for a professional job, place degrees first then coursework. Unless your degree has nothing to do with your coursework, or the job you are interviewing for in the first place.

Mine shows my Certs first because my degree is liberal studies, my certs are IT based. It is better for someone to look at my resume to see my technical skills before my education/degree.

It is always best to customize your resume anyway for each job you apply for.